# JAXB - class customization

Tags: jaxb, duplicates, conflict

How to avoid conflicts when an XSD1 does import an XSD2 and an XSD2 that define the a complex type with the same name ?

Also, how two cope the case when XSD1 does import an XSD2 and an XSD3 that imports XSD2 ?